# CustomExternalUserBuilder not getting called sitecore 9.3

Tags: upgrade, federated-authentication, openid-connect

We have added identity provider for Azure B2C for login into sitecore websites. We need to change the username of virtual user that is created by sitecore after authentication. For that, below code is added and an entry is made to the config file but the code is not getting called.
Please let me know what else we need to add?

Thank you in advance.

```
 public class CustomExternalUserBuilder : ExternalUserBuilder
    {
        private readonly IHashEncryption _hashEncryption;

        public CustomExternalUserBuilder(
          ApplicationUserFactory applicationUserFactory,
          IHashEncryption hashEncryption)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)applicationUserFactory, nameof(applicationUserFactory));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)hashEncryption, nameof(hashEncryption));
            this._hashEncryption = hashEncryption;
            this.ApplicationUserFactory = applicationUserFactory;
        }

        public bool IsPersistentUser { get; set; }

        protected ApplicationUserFactory ApplicationUserFactory { get; }

        public override ApplicationUser BuildUser(
          UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
          ExternalLoginInfo externalLoginInfo)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = this.ApplicationUserFactory.CreateUser(this.CreateUniqueUserName(userManager, externalLoginInfo));
            user.IsVirtual = !this.IsPersistentUser;
            user.Email = externalLoginInfo.Email;
            return user;
        }

        protected virtual string CreateUniqueUserName(
          UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
          ExternalLoginInfo externalLoginInfo)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)userManager, nameof(userManager));
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)externalLoginInfo, nameof(externalLoginInfo));
            var identityProvider = this.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration.GetIdentityProvider(externalLoginInfo.ExternalIdentity)
                                   ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to retrieve an identity provider for the given identity");
            string domain = (identityProvider).Domain;
            string accountName = externalLoginInfo.ExternalIdentity?.FindFirst("AccountName")?.Value;
            string userName = $"{domain}\\{accountName}";
            return userName;
        }
    }
```

Config -

```
<configuration>
  <sitecore>
    <federatedAuthentication>
      <identityProvidersPerSites>
        <mapEntry name="portal" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
          <sites hint="list">
            <site>portal</site>
          </sites>
          <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
            <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='AzureAdB2C']"/>
          </identityProviders>
          <externalUserBuilder type="Portal.SC.Feature.Login.Pipelines.Owin.CustomExternalUserBuilder, Portal.SC.Feature.Login" resolve="true">
            <param desc="isPersistentUser">false</param>
          </externalUserBuilder>
        </mapEntry>
      </identityProvidersPerSites>
    </federatedAuthentication>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If you override `BuildUser` will this get called?

Comment: Hi @Jeroen Thank you for your comment. Could you please elaborate exactly what we need to change here?

Comment: I'm doing this on Sitecore 10 and in my case `CreateUniqueUserName` does not get called either but instead we have `public override ApplicationUser BuildUser(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ExternalLoginInfo externalLoginInfo)`  which gets called and builds user. I would try to add this method in and see if it gets called.

Comment: @NewbieHere You'll need to create your class extending DefaultExternalUserBuilder like this -->  CustomExternalUserBuilder : DefaultExternalUserBuilder

Comment: @Jeroen and Raman , I will try both of your suggestions today. Hope it works out!

Comment: @Jeroen what is the username of the virtual user that sitecore creates after successful authentication from azure ad? In my case it is my name itself. My lead is saying that it should be "{domain_name_provided}/Anonymous". Is it so?

Comment: It should be whatever gets set in ExternalUserBuilder, it shouldn't be Anonymous as the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestions mentioned in the comment didn't work for us. So, instead of defining username in UserBuilder, we added a method with below code that is getting called from our Login Action -

```
 string userName = $"{Context.Domain.Name}\\{userId}";
                    Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User virtualUser = AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(userName, true);
                    virtualUser.SetRoles(user, account, _currentPortalId);
                    AuthenticationManager.Login(virtualUser);
```

This code runs without any errors and we are able to get required username in Context.User.